# Are there limits for AddForbiddenAssignments?

Tags: or-tools

How many tuples can one add to a model with `AddForbiddenAssignments` before they impact solving speed? Thousands, tens of thousands, hundreds of thousands?

I'm finding nothing in the docs, for this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which solver ? CP or CP-SAT.

For the latter, they are quite fast as one tuple is directly translated into one tuple. I would say 10s of thousands. But if you're reach that number, the problem is likely quite big and quite slow anyway.

Comment: Solver is CP-SAT. I would have liked it to select points on a plane (with certain regions not allowed, thus the "not here" flags as forbidden assignments for coordinates).

Comment: Please note that with channeling constraints (https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md), you can remove whole regions easily (i.e. x + y > 1, x in [0..10]).

Comment: The problem's that the regions are arbitrarily-sized, i.e. they come from an image. Not sure, if this is a problem the solver can be applied to.

Comment: You can compute a approximate version by removing large convex linear parts, plus use the ForbiddenAssignment to filter the missing points. Your call.